# MULE 4 : DATAWEAVE 2.0 : How to get the difference in hours between Two Time instances in Dataweave 2.0?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

My requirement is to get the age of a file.
I get the file creation time using `#[attributes.creationTime]`
And to get the Age, I do a difference with the current time.

```
<set-variable value="#[now() - attributes.creationTime]" doc:name="File Duration" doc:id="a7c594b0-3a03-4054-a65a-d32dc08c06e1" variableName="fileAge"/>
```

This sets the fileAge as  : PT-3H-23M-1.577259S

As per the Mule 4 Documentation, https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#duration-coercion

I tried to get the age by doing :

CASE 1 : `vars.fileAge as Number {unit: "hours"}`
and
CASE 2 : `vars.fileAge.hours`

In case 1, i get the error :

```
org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "Cannot coerce Object { encoding: UTF-8, mediaType: application/java; charset=UTF-8, mimeType: application/java, raw: org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.JavaBeanObjectValue$JavaBeanObjectSeq@23e1079b, class: java.time.Duration } ({nano: 422741000 as Number {class: "java.lang.Integer"},units: ["SECONDS" as ...) to Number

1| vars.fileAge as Number {unit: "hours"} 
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 1, column: 1)" evaluating expression: "vars.fileAge as Number {unit: "hours"} ".
```

and in CASE 2, I get Null.

Can someone please help me?

But I am getting an error in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies in DW version or Mule Studio version.
I am using DW 2.0 and Mule studio 7.4.2

When I do the difference : `now() - attributes.creationTime` I get only seconds and nanos in the response. From there if I retrieve seconds and divide by 3600 i get the exact hours as shown in the result of the difference.
But if I try to use the coercion as Number {unit : "hours" } it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Change your variable so that you generate JSON as output:

```
output application/json --- now() - attributes.creationTime
```

The default output when you write a DW expression is `application/java`.  If you pay attention to the type of your variable is set to java's `java.time.Duration` when it should be DW's `Period` if you want to perform the `as Number {units: "hours"}` type-casting.  Switching to JSON allows DW to create a `Period` type for your data.

I bet if I try hard enough I will be able to figure out how (or where I can take `Duration` and casted into a `Period`.  If I get more time later on I 'll look into it or maybe someone else can provide a better answer.

Comment: Hello changing mime type to json or DW converts the output to Period yes. But even then I am not able to extract the hours from the resultant Period. I get same data coercion errors as mentioned above

Comment: What I have provided you above works on my end, I did reuse your expression from above inside a Transform Message processor, `vars.fileAge as Number {unit: "hours"}`.  Maybe you need to share your flow's XML.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the calculation when you're setting `vars.fileAge`. The following dw will output just the difference in hours between two DateTimes. Tested on DW 2.3.0

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var creationTime = "2020-07-17T10:16:53.196Z"
---
(now() - creationTime) as Number {unit: "hours"}
```

Comment: I tried doing the above and as mentioned in the question I get the Error that Datatype coercion is not allowed : "Cannot coerce Period (|PT-4H-33M-34.157073S|) to Number"